# Is there anything wrong in these two methods that copy & returns an array

Tags: java, arrays

Is there anything wrong in these two methods that copy & returns an array?

This is how i called it :

> ```
>        o2[i].addArr(o1.getArr());
> ```

And at the end the result is that `o2[i].getArr();` is empty. I don't know why but this is my code if you could help me

> NOTE: The class Array i wrote it here Array while it's another class name in my code. just to make it clear for you

```
public Array[] getArr(){ //first method
     int count=0;

     for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(Arrlist[i]!=null)
           count++;}

     Array[] arr=new Array[count];

     for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        arr[i]=Arrlist[i];
     return arr;}

public void addArr(Array[]arr){ //second method
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
Arrlist[i]=arr[i];

}
```

Comment: "Is there anything wrong?" is quite a wide question. Are you asking about code style? About bugs? About naming? Etc. I would raise issues with all of the above!

Comment: *"NOTE: The class Array i wrote it here Array while it's another class name in my code. just to make it clear for you"* I'd've used just about any other name than `Array` in that case.

Comment: please read my comment on the first answer below

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In `getArr`, you're going to overrun the length of the array you're creating if you have any `null` entries in the array you're copying.

In the loop where you're actually copying, you need *separate* variables for the index into `arr` and the index into `Arrlist`, because you need to skip `null`s.

E.g., along these lines (untested):

```
int i, j;

j = 0;
for (i = 0; i < Arrlist.length; ++i) {
    if (Arrlist[i] != null) {
        arr[j++] = Arrlist[i];
    }
}
```

`addArr` is okay **if** (and it's a big "if") `Arrlist` is allocated and it's the same size as `arr`. (You could replace it with [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29).) Note that the name is misleading, though; you're *overwriting* `Arrlist`, not adding to it. And again, those are some pretty big "if"s.

Comment: When i call this method and store the array that it returns into a variable called x[]. When i say x[0].toString() it gives me a null pointer exception :(